# Cannot configure SigningProvider for Sitecore.Services.Client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore

In *Sitecore.Services.Client.config* there is a setting to enable the new token-based authorization in Sitecore 8.2. Setting this to 'true' however gives me the following error in Postman when trying to make any call to WebAPI (to ItemService or any of my custom actions):

[image]

I'm at a loss however as to where this is configured:

[image]

I checked the *Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Configuration.ServicesConfiguration* object itself but it doesn't seem to have a place to configure this:

[image]

Removing the *TokenDelegatingHandler* from the config seems to make the API work again but calling **sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login** throws a 500 Internal Server Error.

[More info about this feature at the CoreBlimey Sitecore blog](http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/token-based-authentication-with-sitecore-services-client/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the steps here:

http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/token-based-authentication-with-sitecore-services-client/

It seems to indicate you need to add a tag for the token provider:

```
<tokenSecurity>
  <signingProvider type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Security.SymetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore">
           <param desc="connectionStringName">Sitecore.Services.Token.SecurityKey</param>
   </signingProvider>
</tokenSecurity>
```

I would personally advise doing this in a patch configuration file, and not in the OOTB Sitecore config file, though.

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work. I already linked to that article in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The code for loading the signing provider is here in the: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.dll so there wont be property on the class.

```
  namespace Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Security
  {
   public class ConfigurationSigningProviderFactory : ISigningProviderFactory
   {
      public ISigningProvider Create()
      {
        XmlNode configNode = 
        Factory.GetConfigNode("/sitecore/api/tokenSecurity/signingProvider");
       if (configNode != null)
            return Factory.CreateObject<ISigningProvider>(configNode);
          return (ISigningProvider) null;
      }
   }
}
```

UPDATE: The signing provider should be placed in a patch file like so:

```
<configuration>
   <sitecore>
      <api>
         <tokenSecurity> 
            <signingProvider type="sitecore.services.infrastructure.sitecore.security.symetrickeysigningprovider, sitecore.services.infrastructure.sitecore">
              <param desc="connectionstringname">sitecore.services.token.securitykey</param> 
            </signingProvider>
       </tokenSecurity>
      <api>
   </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't work which is why I asked this question. As I implied in my post, tokenSecurity is not a property of ServicesConfiguration.

Comment: What version of 8.2 are you using update 1,2 or 3? I've tested it in 1 and 2.